# Шенкурский проезд

Tags: орфоэпия

Возможно, я задаю не совсем подходящий вопрос для этого сайта. Но я читал на каком-то сайте список московских улиц с правильными ударениями, в названиях которых чаще всего делают ошибки. В числе прочих там был Шенкурский проезд с ударением на Е. Это ударение подтвердила и [Грамота](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/moscow?alpha=%D0%A8), но... Потом я увидел в [статье Википедии об этой улице](https://ru.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=%D0%A8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B4&stable=1) другое ударение (на У). В свою очередь город, по которому названа улица в Википедии значится как Ш**е**нкурск, а [энциклопедия на Академике](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/es/65001/%D0%A8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BA) даёт ударение на У, равно как и моя (бумажная) советская энциклопедия 1987 года. В [обсуждении указанной статьи о проезде в Википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%81%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5:%D0%A8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B4) сторонники ударения на У, которые добились указания двух вариантов ударения, а потом изменения на ударение на У (вначале в статье ударение было на Е), ссылаются на ту же страничку о проезде на Академике, а также живущие в том районе в один голос говорят, что местные ***никогда*** не называют проезд Ш**е**нкурским.

Так как же быть? Что считать более авторитетным источником: Грамоту или энциклопедию? И если даже есть основания считать, что Грамота права, имеет ли смысл делать ударение на Е и выделяться из всех, быть белой вороной? А с другой стороны не хочется идти на поводу у тех, кто всё переиначивает, как, например, Планёрную улицу и метро переделали в Пл**а**нерную, а также Кадашёвские переулки в Кадаш**е**вские или даже Кад**а**шевкие (хоть это и не стало нормой, но даже я с удивлением увидел Ё на табличке полгода назад (спасибо тем, кто восстановил букву Ё в топонимах Москвы!!!)).

Comment: Артем, ударение в русском языке подвижное. Вот поэтому,возможно, в силу распространенности этих вариантов в словаре указали два варианта.  Почему сомневаетесь?

Comment: Подвижность ударения - это другое явление, применимое главным образом к вопросам ***формообразования***. Связанное с переносом ударения на разные части (в основном - с окончания на корень и наоборот) при склонении, реже - спряжении.

Answer (score 1):

Назван в 1974 г. по древнему городу Шенкурск, райцентру Архангельской области, упоминаемому в документах с 1137 г. До 1978 г. назывался проездом Есенина.

Селение упоминается в истор. актах с XIV в. как Шенга-Курья, т. г 'на курье реки Шенги'. В названии курья 'речной залив, заводь, узкий проток реки', а Шенга (совр. Шеньга) название реки, пп Ваги (ср. саам. senV 'осоковое болото'). За века, прошедшие после возникновения названия, произошли значительные русловые изменения, и сейчас город оказался на берегу Вага, в 10 км ниже устья Шеньги.

Из Словаря В. Даля: «курья — разливной приток, которому нет названья. Шенкурск стоит при впадении Шенги в Вагу, отчего названье *шенкурья*, Шенкурск».

Поскольку вторая составляющая ***курья*** ударяется словарями исключительно на Я, но ему не отведено места в сложном ***Шенкурск***, ударение сохраняется за первой: Шен.

Comment: Ну, да, это согласно одному источнику. Согласно другому будет по-другому.  Так что основательного ответа на вопрос "кому всё-таки доверять" что-то я не вижу.

Answer (score 1):

А в чем собственно вопрос? Как правильно или почему так происходит?

Правильно здесь, думаю, Ш**е**нкурский, коли этот вариант пока дают более авторитетные источники. Но топонимы вещь такая, что со временем может измениться нормативность. Очень может быть, что под влиянием аборигенов и масс вообще норма изменится.

С Планёрной/Планерной трудно сравнивать: там изменилась (частично) нормативность исходного **нарицательного** слова.

Comment: Спасибо, Ирина!

Answer (score 1):

В Шенкурске все ударение ставят на первый слог (я сам шенкурЯнин).

Comment: "Шенку́рск — город в России, административный центр Шенкурского района Архангельской области. Единственный населённый пункт, входящий в состав городского поселения Шенкурское".

Comment: Спасибо большое, очень интересно!

Answer (score 0):

Я бы попробовал найти кого-нибудь из города ***Шенкурска*** и спросить, на какой слог ударение приходится в названии их города и района.  Название района совпадает по написанию с названием проезда.

Возможно есть какие-нибудь записи заседания их городского органа власти или районного.  И хотя есть, конечно, опасность, что кто-то из местных жителей делает неверное ударение, вероятность не так уж велика.

Comment: Допустим, город однозначно Ш**е**нкурском окажется. Но что делать с тем, что все реально называют проезд Шенк**у**рским (если это правда), хотя и правильно однозначно говорить Ш**е**нкурский (**в случае, если предположение верно**)?

Comment: Виктор, горожане Шенкурска тоже могут ошибаться.

Comment: http://mosfo.ru/o-moskve/stavim-pravilno-udareniya-v-nazvaniyah-ulic-moskvy